# Getting unique values from multiple fields as matched using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, unique-value

There are `"Code"` and `"Color"` fields in my layer like this: (Sample 6 rows)

| Code | Color |
| --- | --- |
| A | Red |
| B | Blue |
| A | Red |
| A | Red |
| B | Blue |
| C | Green |

All `A`s are `Red`, all `B`s are `Blue` and so on.

I can get the unique values for each field:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

code_index = layer.fields().indexFromName("Code")
code_unique = layer.uniqueValues(code_index)

color_index = layer.fields().indexFromName("Color")
color_unique = layer.uniqueValues(color_index)

print(code_unique)
print(color_unique)

# OUTPUT
# {'A', 'C', 'B'}
# {'Blue', 'Red', 'Green'}
```

As you can see, the order of two outputs doesn't match. (When you try, you might get an ordered result, but it depends and is not reliable)

How can I get unique value pairs like `[('A', 'Red'), ('B', 'Blue'), ('C', 'Green')]` using PyQGIS?

I couldn't find `groupby`-like method. It can be done by means of `groupby(["Code", "Color"]).first()` in GeoPandas.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `set()` which is a Python built-in function.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()    

pairs = list(set([(f["Code"], f["Color"]) for f in layer.getFeatures()]))

print(pairs) # [('A', 'Red'), ('C', 'Green'), ('B', 'Blue')]
```

A [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) is an unordered data structure, so it does not preserve the insertion order. You will probably get an unordered but a matched list (`('A', 'Red') ('C', 'Green'), ...`).

Comment: No need `list()`, if `pairs` will be used in a loop (like `for p in pairs`). Thanks.

Comment: you can also put into a dict instead of list, that would make it easy to call by keys later

Answer (score 10):

You can use the class `Counter()` from the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) module.

```py
from collections import Counter

layer = iface.activeLayer()

c = Counter([(feat['Code'],feat['Color']) for feat in layer.getFeatures()])
print(c) # Counter({('A', 'Red'): 3, ('B', 'Blue'): 2, ('C', 'Green'): 1})

combination = [comb for comb in c]
print(combination) # [('A', 'Red'), ('B', 'Blue'), ('C', 'Green')]
```